# localstorege every time update new one

Tags: javascript, local-storage, iterable

hi can you please explain why every time i add an item to local storage it gets updated instead of adding a new item ,,i guess for my code id isn't unique ,,,, but i can't understand how to fix it ....

here is code

https://jsfiddle.net/adulik/8sqbcox2/28/

```js
//add task list item
function addTaskListItem(id) {
    //get element by id
    const task = document.getElementById(id);
    let getItemFromStorage =  localStorage.getItem("data-item")
    if(!getItemFromStorage){
        getItemFromStorage = JSON.parse(getItemFromStorage)
        getItemFromStorage = [...getItemFromStorage,task.value]
        console.log("storage",getItemFromStorage)

    }else {
        localStorage.setItem("data-item", JSON.stringify([task.value]))

    }

}
```

Comment: Your are getting and parsing the item `if(!getItemFromStorage)`.. so `JSON.parse(undefined)`. Shouldn't it be the contrary ? `if(getItemFromStorage){/*get item, parse item*/ } else {/*set item*/}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you twisted your condition. It should be `if(getItemFromStorage)`

```
//add task list item
function addTaskListItem(id) {
    //get element by id
    const task = document.getElementById(id);
    let getItemFromStorage =  localStorage.getItem("data-item")
    if(getItemFromStorage){ //modified the condition here from `!getItemFromStorage` to `getItemFromStorage`
        getItemFromStorage = JSON.parse(getItemFromStorage)
        getItemFromStorage = [...getItemFromStorage,task.value]
        console.log("storage",getItemFromStorage)
        localStorage.setItem("data-item", JSON.stringify(getItemFromStorage)) //update local storage with latest tasks
    }else {
        localStorage.setItem("data-item", JSON.stringify([task.value]))

    }

}
```

It's working fine after that modification https://jsfiddle.net/n7Lj3zdx/

Comment: thank you ))) ,,,,but now it update last element in storage)

Comment: I added 1 more line of code there that will keep your local storage at the latest state always, you can check it out @help

Answer (score 0):

Because you update the "data-item", not append new data into it.

```
localStorage.setItem("data-item", JSON.stringify([task.value]))
```

It should be something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("data-item", JSON.stringify([...ItemFromStorage].append(newItem))
```